# Nginx is catching Laravel request errors, or so it seems

Tags: laravel, nginx, exception, laravel-valet, php-7.4

I am working in a Laravel Valet php7.4 environment, on a Laravel 7.4 app. With this, I have created a form request that updates a user's bio, with the following validation:
`'bio' => ['nullable', 'max:255']`

Whenever I put a huge amount of characters in, my local (Nginx) server seems to collapse and Laravel isn't pooping out the error by validation. I was getting Valet 502 Bad Gateway errors, that I fixed by adding this to the valet config:

```
fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
```

Now the 502 errors are gone, but it is still not Laravel that is catching the request error. Any ideas why?

Edit: some more information on the request part

Form:

```
<form
    class="form"
    method="POST"
    action="{{ route('settings.profile.update') }}"
>
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('PATCH') }}

    <div class="form-group">
        <x-input-textarea
            label="Bio"
            name="bio"
            :value="$user->profile->bio"
            ref="bio"
        />
    </div>
    
    <x-button
        class="button--primary"
        label="Opslaan"
    />
</form>
```

The textarea Blade component

```
<div class="form-field">
    @isset( $label )
        <label class="label" for="{{ $name }}">{{ $label }}</label>
    @endif

    <textarea
        {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => "input input--textarea"]) }}
        name="{{ $name }}"
        id="{{ $name }}"
        placeholder="{{ $placeholder ?? ($label ?? null) }}"
        {{ ($required ?? false) ? 'required' : '' }}
        {{ isset($autocomplete) ? 'autocomplete=' . $autocomplete : '' }}
    >{{ old($name, $value ?? '') }}</textarea>

    @if( $errors->has($name) )
        <x-input-message
            :message="$errors->first($name)"
        />
    @elseif( $hint )
        <p class="mt-xxsmall text-meta">
            {{ $hint }}
        </p>
    @endif
</div>
```

The Controller

```
public function update(ProfileRequest $request)
{
    ...// authorization

    // job
    ProfileUpdateJob::dispatchNow($request, $user);

    ...// returning stuff
}
```

The Profile Update Job

```
public function handle()
{
    $input = $this->request->validated();
    $this->user->profile()->update($input);
}
```

Comment: Can you share your form handling action?

Comment: I've edited my original post @Unflux

Answer (score 0):

I was also having this issue, even after tweaking my nginx configuration. In the end, the issue was addressed when I changed my `LOG_CHANNEL` from `errorlog` to something else, such as `daily` (note: `stack` may have `errorlog` in it, so watch out for that). Debugging this further, it seemed the stacktrace logged when `errorlog` is used, is too large for php to return back to nginx, hence the generic nginx 500 error. This may be able to be resolved by further tweaking the nginx settings, but I couldn't resolve it that way.